# Why does a missing parenthesis error occur on this code

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running this query and I keep getting  a missing right parenthesis error message. Query is part of a larger query. Larger query runs fine and I am getting the missing parenthesis error once I add the below code.

```
 (( SELECT (CASE WHEN NAME = 'ELP' THEN 
                 'ELP'
                 WHEN NAME  = 'MDP' THEN 'MDP'
                 ELSE 'Other'
                 END ) AS P_TYPE
                 FROM JOB_INFORMATION_D 
                 INNER JOIN EVENT_F 
                      ON EVENT_F.JOB_INFO_ROW_ =JOB_INFORMATION_D.ROW_WID
                      INNER CANDIDATE_D ON CANDIDATE_D.ROW_WID =     EVENT_F.CANDIDATE_ROW_WID
                     WHERE STS_NAME = 'Extended'
                     AND STEP_NAME = 'Offer'
              AND inner.PZNUM = OUTERAPP.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM

              ORDER BY DT ASC) T1 WHERE ROWNUM=1),
```

Comment: Find the following line: `INNER CANDIDATE_D ON ....` - you are missing the keyword `JOIN` after `INNER`.

Comment: You also have `AND inner.PZNUM = ...` later in your code. That is very confusing; do you have a table or view named (or aliased to) `inner`? That's bad - don't use Oracle keywords as identifiers (table or column names, function names, etc.)

Comment: thanks, that pointed me to some of my issue, I had edited the code and ended deleting some stuff out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two WHERE-clauses but only one SELECT-statement. The second WHERE-clause is outside of the SELECT in parentheses and therefore does not belong to any SELECT.

Also as @mathguy says, there is a missing JOIN-keyword.

Rewrite the statement as

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT
        CASE WHEN NAME = 'ELP' THEN 'ELP'
             WHEN NAME  = 'MDP' THEN 'MDP'
             ELSE 'Other'
        END AS P_TYPE
    FROM
        JOB_INFORMATION_D
        INNER JOIN EVENT_F
            ON EVENT_F.JOB_INFO_ROW_ = JOB_INFORMATION_D.ROW_WID
        INNER JOIN CANDIDATE_D
            ON CANDIDATE_D.ROW_WID = EVENT_F.CANDIDATE_ROW_WID
    WHERE
        STS_NAME = 'Extended' AND
        STEP_NAME = 'Offer' AND
        inner.PZNUM = OUTERAPP.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
    ORDER BY DT ASC
  )
WHERE
    ROWNUM = 1
```

Also there are these `inner.PZNUM` and `OUTERAPP.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM`, but there are no tables named `inner` and `OUTERAPP`. Either this SQL is completely wrong, or you did not show us the whole command.

You should consequently use table aliases and then prefix all used columns with these aliases. Like it is now, one does not see to which table the columns belong.

```
...
FROM
    JOB_INFORMATION_D J
    INNER JOIN EVENT_F E
        ON E.JOB_INFO_ROW_ = J.ROW_WID
    INNER JOIN CANDIDATE_D C
        ON C.ROW_WID = E.CANDIDATE_ROW_WID
...
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. The query above was just subset of a larger query so it wasn't the whole command